# SSIS Error: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard Edition (64-bit) of Integration Services or higher

Tags: sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent, ssis-2016

- SQL Server 2016 SP1 Enterprise Edition Data Engine (with SQL Agent) installed on an FCI called inst1.
- SSIS 2016 SP1 Enterprise Edition installed on comp2. (comp2 is not in the inst1 cluster)
- Filesystem SSIS packages on comp2.
- SQL Agent job using the SSIS step type on inst1 calls the package store on comp2.

When I run the job on inst1, I get this error:

> To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard Edition (64-bit) of Integration Services or higher.

I have run the edition upgrade wizard, just in case the wrong edition was installed. The error persists.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this package use Excel files?

Comment: No it does not use Excel files.

Comment: What package deployment model is it using?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I didn't have SSIS installed on the inst1 server(s) and that is where the dtexec.exe process was being kicked off. It was not an edition problem, just a missing service problem.